# Other pages not loading in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a beginner to codeigniter and I am trying to get an old project started. When I load the homepage it loads fine (login page). However when I click to go any other page (sign up or forget password) it goes back to localhost.

I have a base url set in my **config.php** file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/website/';
```

and the autoloader is activated in **autoload.php**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','file','form','html');
```

Any help on getting this to work will be greatly appreciated.

An example of the anchor tag for one of the links is:

```
<h1>Login <?php echo anchor('signup', 'Sign Up', 'class="btn btn-link" title="Sign Up"' ); ?></h1>
```

Comment: what is the value for href in anchor tags ? can you show your code ?

Comment: `http://localhost/website/` looks like you installed it in a subdirectory, so try to install it at the root of the webserver and see if it works.

Comment: is the root directory -website- is under htdocs ?

Comment: the root directory website is under htdocs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609613/codeigniter-not-loading-pages

Comment: did you check your .htaccess file of codeigniter

Comment: @MohitJain what about the .htaccess file should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in config.php**

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$root";
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I do not know how you are linking your anchor tags but here is one way of doing it:

```
<?php echo base_url();?>controller/function_name
```

Make sure the folder hierarchy in the root in your localhost is proper . I mean that if the project folder name is "website", make sure the Codeigniter files like application, resources are not in a subdirectory but directly inside the folder "website".

For your signup, try using this syntax :

```
<?php echo base_url();?>controller/signup
```

Add this in your htaccess file in the root directory :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers !

Comment: this didn't work. I put the folder in the root itself and now I get a 404 error when using a link.

Comment: will check this and get back to you